# dynamic data range for vba chart

Tags: vba, excel

The below mentioned code is working properly. But then my query is:---
currently I am having Input datasheet value from A1 to P4 but it can change: for example datavalue can be from A1 to S7. (the data always starts with A in excel sheet) 
But in the code given below, I have given the range manually. what changes i need to do in range part so that it will automatically find out the column range?

```
            Sub to_Draw_chart()
               Dim ws_InputSheet As String 
               ws_InputSheet = "Sheet3"
               Charts.Add
               ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnStacked
               ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets(ws_InputSheet).Range(ws_InputSheet & "!$A$1:$P$4"), PlotBy:=xlColumns
               With ActiveChart
                   .HasTitle = True
                   .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "Time_Plotter"
                   .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 1000
                   .Axes(xlValue).MajorUnit = 250
                   .Axes(xlCategory).CategoryType = xlCategoryScale
                   .Axes(xlCategory).CategoryType = xlAutomatic
               End Sub
```

Comment: @siddarthRout just to grab your attention any chance you could help me out with a problem I posted, thanks

Comment: try the code in my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used your **ws_InputSheet** but `As WorkSheet`, I think you'll find the code below simplier to follow:

```
Option Explicit

Sub to_Draw_chart()

    Dim ws_InputSheet As Worksheet, ws_OutputSheet As Worksheet
    Dim dataRng As Range

    Set ws_InputSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")

    With ws_InputSheet
        Set dataRng = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    End With

    Charts.Add
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnStacked

    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=dataRng, PlotBy:=xlColumns
    With ActiveChart
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "Time_Plotter"
        .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 1000
        .Axes(xlValue).MajorUnit = 250
        .Axes(xlCategory).CategoryType = xlCategoryScale
        .Axes(xlCategory).CategoryType = xlAutomatic
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: i tried the code given by you. but then it is showing compiler error. With object must be user defined type, Object / Variant. The code is breaking at With ws_InputSheet.

Comment: @user28 did you change the definition to `Dim ws_InputSheet As Worksheet` ? and later did you set it to `Set ws_InputSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")` ?

Comment: thank you very much. it worked. yes i didn't change Dim ws_InputSheet As Worksheet . but now everythng is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub to_Draw_chart()
    Dim ws_InputSheet As String, ws_OutputSheet As String

    ws_InputSheet = "Sheet3"

    Dim dataRng As Range
    With Worksheets(ws_InputSheet)
        Set dataRng = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    End With

    Charts.Add
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnStacked
'    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets(ws_OutputSheet).Range(ws_InputSheet & "!$A$1:$P$4"), PlotBy:=xlColumns
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets(ws_OutputSheet).Range(dataRng.Address(True, True, True, True)), PlotBy:=xlColumns
    With ActiveChart
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "Time_Plotter"
        .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 1000
        .Axes(xlValue).MajorUnit = 250
        .Axes(xlCategory).CategoryType = xlCategoryScale
        .Axes(xlCategory).CategoryType = xlAutomatic
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets(ws_OutputSheet).Range(dataRng.Address(True, True, True, True)), PlotBy:=xlColumns
    at this line of code, Run time error 1004: Application defined or object defined error is showing up.. @user3598756

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code. This will create the chart from the active selection

```
Sub to_Draw_chart()
    Dim ws_InputSheet As String
    Dim SelRange As Range
    Sheets("Sheet3").Activate
    Set SelRange = Selection
    ws_InputSheet = "Sheet3"
    Charts.Add
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnStacked
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=SelRange, PlotBy:=xlColumns
    With ActiveChart
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "Time_Plotter"
        .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 1000
        .Axes(xlValue).MajorUnit = 250
        .Axes(xlCategory).CategoryType = xlCategoryScale
        .Axes(xlCategory).CategoryType = xlAutomatic
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: i tried this code, but it is just generating the blank chart without any data being plotted.. my question is where in this code it has been mentioned that it should select data from Sheet3?? and also active selection means the cells in the excel sheet which are selected , Is it what it means??

Comment: yes. Exactly. therefore if your are in a different sheet when you running this, then you need to switch to sheet3 for this code to work. that is to include `Sheets("Sheet3").Activate` before `Set SelRange = Selection`